# Inter domain cookies in Tomcat 7 via XML config

Tags: java, xml, cookies, tomcat7

I've been tasked with modifying an application, of which I have access to the XML configuration of it in what appears to be Tomcat 7.

I need a cookie (called `oname` to be specific) shared to another domain (example.com). That is to say that, an iframe on the application to example.com can share the cookies from the application.

First of all, is this possible? Second of all, if it is (which I hope it is! :)) how can I do it via XML and XML only (referring to the configuration files found in the base of the application).

I've done some research on cookies, and I determined I need to modify the `domain` section on all cookies. If I need to change change all cookies globally (e.g. adding an XML element within the configuration to add `domain = example.com` to all cookies then that's acceptable!

I've pretty much have 2 options:

1. Find a specific XML element to change all cookies globally to add my desired domain
2. Have a JavaScript shim on the client side (I have access to the HTML also) wrap around the normal method to set cookies, while also adding `example.com` to the domain bit on the cookies.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If your application is running on `www.example.com`, it can set a cookie for `.example.com`, but not if it's running on any other domain than `example.com`. If it would be possible to set cookies for unrelated domains, Anybody could easily set a cookie for any other random site, and as cookie names are typically well predictable, interfere with those sites (e.g. setting jsessionid or other session- and identification cookies in a rogue way).

Your only option is if the other site cooperates and provides a URL that you can redirect to which sets the cookie itself. Beware: Without checking the validity of the request, anybody can redirect to that site and set a cookie through the same measures - you can easily introduce a security issue.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I didn't think of that! :)